# Accessing drupal $user object from codeigniter

Tags: drupal

I have a Drupal instance(`localhost/drupal-7.22`) and a CodeIgniter instance (`localhost/drupal-7.22/codeigniter_2.1.3`) in my local machine. Now I need to access the drupal session from my CodeIgniter app. The reason why I need the session details is, using that details only I am showing data in my CodeIgniter app (FYI: CodeIgniter app is called from Drupal using an iframe).

I have tried to get the $user object by using the following code.

```
class loginCheck{

function __construct(){

    // define static var
    define('DRUPAL_ROOT', dirname(__FILE__)."/../");
    // include bootstrap

    include_once(dirname(__FILE__).'/../includes/bootstrap.inc');
    // initialize stuff
    drupal_bootstrap(DRUPAL_BOOTSTRAP_SESSION);

}

function checkLogin(){
    global $user;

    if($user->uid >0){
        // user logged in
        var_dump($user);
    }
    else{
        // anonym user
        echo '{"data":"0"}';    
    }
}
}
$loginCheck = new loginCheckk();
$loginCheck->checkLogin();
```

Comment: Change the drupal_bootstrap parameter to: drupal_bootstrap(DRUPAL_BOOTSTRAP_FULL);

Whats the value of DRUPAL_ROOT?

Comment: @mario: i have tried that too.. And the value of DRUPAL_ROOT ill be "localhost/drupal-7.22/" which s the root directory of my drupal installation.